# I am struggling to connect my data class to the rest of my code. Its causing a unresolved reference within my code

Tags: java, android, kotlin

The code where the issue is is below, both placeresponse are called unresolved references.

```kotlin
fun read(): List<Place> {
    val itemType = object : TypeToken<List<PlaceResponse>>() {}.type
    val reader = InputStreamReader(inputStream)
    return gson.fromJson<List<PlaceResponse>>(reader, itemType).map {
        it.toPlace()
    }
```

Comment: do you have the correct imports for these classes ?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to coding, where do I find the imports. And what imports should I have?

Comment: I currently have auto import setting turned on.